# Group policy not allowing url to be added

Tags: internet-explorer, group-policy

I'm trying to add a specific web server URL into the local Intranet Zone on my client PCs using a Group Policy. The policy works for all remote sites but does not work for the local site where the data center is located at. It works for the IT department but not for anyone else here. Please help.

Comment: There are a couple ways to set zones through group policies.  Can you tell us exactly which policy you are trying to apply?  Is it a per-user policy?  Is the policy set to apply to administrators?  Have you ran the Group Policy Results Wizard or Modeling Wizard?

Comment: It is set to apply to user policy.

Comment: I asked you a series of questions to help you add more detail to your question.  Your reply is not very useful.  Please take some time and provide **more detail**.  At the moment you really haven't given us enough information to work with here.  We cannot read your mind, and we don't know how you have things setup on your network.

Comment: We have set in several policy that the users use. We set it up on the domain group policy, and a few other policies.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be performing a resultant set of policy (RSoP) on a functioning client/user and one that doesn't.  Sounds like either a configuration problem or a policy conflict.  For example, you may have a policy with loopback processing enabled.